# How to place image to 1/1 canvas in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I upload image how can I change it with Image Intervention package:

```
$img = $request->file('image');
$img->store('users/' . auth()->user()->id, ['disk' => 'public']);
```

Now I don't want to resize this image but to place it on canvas centered.

```
$canvas = Image::canvas(245, 245);
```

And if `$img is 230x100 or 100x230;` I want to horizontally and vertically center it on canvas.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The intervention package provide height and width. You can use it as below.

```
$img = $request->file('image');
$image = Image::make($img);

$width = $image->width();
$height= $image->height();

$canvas = Image::canvas($width, $height);
$img->store('users/' . auth()->user()->id, ['disk' => 'public']);
```